# Granting roles to user ORACLE using JDBC in Java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, sql-grant

I would like to know if it is possible to grant roles to specific users in Oracle using JDBC as connector in Java. I have the following sentence. I don't know which of the functions I have to use in JDBC.

```
st = con.createStatement();
String priv = "connect, resource";
String query = String.format("grant %s to %s ", priv, user);
success = st.execute(q);
```

I have tried using the sentence above, but Oracle sends me back false as response. There's no error message.

Comment: What do you mean by "false statements"?  Is there an error message?  If so, please post the message and any stack trace.

Comment: It returns false all the times.

Answer (score 2):

The [`execute` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute-java.lang.String-) returns a `boolean` indicating whether there is a `ResultSet` to be retrieved.  Because this is a grant statement, there is no `ResultSet`.

> Returns:
>
> true if the first result is a ResultSet object; false if it is an update count or there are no results

There is nothing wrong with a `false` return value here.  Your statement seems to have executed successfully.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know it, that's why my function always returned false as if the operation went wrong. Now I know it was everything okay.